# Check if value of keys is a string with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I have an object like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  type1: 'Adjective',
  type2: 'Noun',
  type3: 'Noun',
  type4: 'Noun',
  type5: 'Plural Noun',
  type6: 'Person',
  type7: 'Place',
  type8: 'Job',
  type9: 'Adjective',
  type10: 'Adjective',
  type11: 'Famous Person',
  type12: 'Noun',
  type13: 'Noun',
  type14: '',
  createdAt: 2019-10-11T06:49:38.000Z,
  updatedAt: 2019-10-11T06:49:38.000Z
}
```

Is there any way that I can only get the keys where the values are a string using handlebars helpers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write handlebars configuration helper which can check this

```
module.exports.hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    helpers: {
        //You can Name this anything
        checkIfValuesOfJsonAreStrings: function(jsonList, context) {
        for (var key in obj) {
         if(typeOf obj[key] == "String"){

        }else{
           return context.inverse(this); // This False
        }
      }
      return context.fn(this)
    }
})
```

Now When writing your .hbs code you can include

```
{{# checkIfValuesOfJsonAreStrings}}
   <div>Yah all the values in JSON are string</div>
{{/checkIfValuesOfJsonAreStrings}}
```